# C++ inline assembly error

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I'm trying to insert a JMP instruction using inline assembly but i get an error saying :

"Expected expression"

```
// Allocate a place in memory for the bytes 
BYTE *jmp = (BYTE*)malloc(len + 5);

// Copy the bytes of original + length to the allocated memory place:
memcpy(jmp, orig, len);

// Next we want to insert a jump back to the original + length 
jmp += len; // increment to the end of the copied bytes
jmp[0] = _asm JMP   // this is where i get the error

*(DWORD*)(jmp + 1) = (DWORD)(orig + len - jmp) - 5;
```

I am new to assembly and would like to know a way of achieving this goal in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jmp[0] = _asm JMP
```

Can never work as the *opcode* (byte(s) representing the instruction) for `JMP` depends on the *operand* (argument to the instruction). See [Vol. 2A 3-433](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf) in Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual.

It looks like you're after `JMP rel32` in which case you should substitute `0xE9` for `_asm JMP`.

For more information I recommend the linked Intel documents or one of the other many sources on x86 instruction encoding on the net. E.g. [this one from osdev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding).